# Реализация вращения изображения при скролле страницы на jq

Tags: javascript, jquery

Доброго времени суток. Помогите пожалуйста пытаюсь реализовать так:

```
var el = $('.ellipse2'),
      pageHeight = document.documentElement.scrollHeight,
      viewportHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;

$(window).on('scroll', function (e) {
    var scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;

    el.css("transform", "rotate('+variable+')", (scrollTop+viewportHeight) / "1500" )
});
```

С opacity работает отлично в виде:

```
el.css("opacity", (scrollTop+viewportHeight) / "1500" )
```

Не пойму как правильно прописать для rotate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

там где "rotate('+variable+')" - variable подразумевается что нужно подставить значение

```
var el = $('.ellipse2'),
      pageHeight = document.documentElement.scrollHeight,
      viewportHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;

$(window).on('scroll', function (e) {
    var scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;

    el.css("transform", "rotate(" + (scrollTop+viewportHeight) / 1500 + "deg)" )

});
```

Comment: Благодарю. Очень помогли!)